# Build error while trying to run Yolo3 example in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, build

So, I am trying to run a project that involves the usage of the inbuilt Yolo model provided by OpenCV in C++. However, when I try to create the model it gives me the error "dnn_backend_opencv wasn't declared in this scope."Now I have included the namespaces cv,dnn, and std, but it still gives me the error.
Furthermore, I also get the error no known conversion from double to Mat when it reaches the line blobfromImage()
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more information if you want help. We need reproducible example code and the exact error message.

Comment: I was able to solve the earlier problem,but now I am running into a new issue.The source code is provided in the below link.

Comment: https://github.com/udacity/SFND_3D_Object_Tracking

Comment: The new error is as follows #1 : LOAD IMAGE INTO BUFFER done
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what(): OpenCV(4.1.0) /home/kieranych/SFND/opencv/opencv-4.1.0/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:694: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Transpose the weights (except for convolutional) is not implemented in function 'ReadDarknetFromWeightsStream'

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Apologies for the previous comments.A detailed and clearer explanation is as follows

Comment: System Information:
OpenCV>=4.0
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04
compiler:GCC 5.4.0
Description: While working on a course project that relies  on the yolo3 model to make detections I ran into the following error:
#1 : LOAD IMAGE INTO BUFFER done
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what(): OpenCV(4.1.0) /home/kieranych/SFND/opencv/opencv-4.1.0/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:694: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Transpose the weights (except for convolutional) is not implemented in function 'ReadDarknetFromWeightsStream'

Aborted

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
1)Clone the following repository: https://github.com/udacity/SFND_3D_Object_Tracking
2)mkdir build & cd build
3)cmake .. & make
4).3D_object_tracking
Further Dependencies:
cmake>=2.8
Git LFS
OpenCV>=4.1
gcc/g++>=5.4

Comment: Please use the edit button of your post above and use code marks (3 backticks) to paste your error lines. In a comment, it's not readable.